# Parsing XML Files by constructing an Object Model

Tags: xml, code-generation, xsd, xsd.exe

I've always preferred using XSD.exe/VS.Net to generate schema, generate classes off the schema, deserialize xml file into object tree to parse an XML file. [Well, most of my requirements thus far have made this a perfect choice].

I've a crib though:  The class names generated by XSD.exe are weird - meaning XSD.exe strives to keep them unique by concatnating all the preceding ancester tag names.

Is there a way I could customize this?  Or perhaps a tool to run on top of this?

My motive is to keep *auto generated* code inviolate.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like its the schema being autogenerated that is causing the problem.  I've used the class generation part of XSD.exe and the class have usually been fine.

If the schema is being automatically generated then its probably going to need a bit of tweaking manually to correct the crazy node names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really starting to wish for a simple way to alter the output of xsd.exe without resorting to hacking codedom... seems like a project that just "needs to happen"...